# Result regarding mutual information of bounded random variable

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

I have a random variable $X$ which takes values in $[0,1].$ Thus $X$ can be written as 
$$
X=0.X_1X_2...X_k.....
$$
where $(X_1,X_2,...,X_k)$ denotes the random vector corresponding to first $k$-bits of $X.$ Let $X_1^k=(X_1,X_2,...,X_k),\ X_{k+1}^{\infty}=(X_{k+1},X_{k+2},...)$. I am trying to prove the following:

$$
I(X_1^k;X_{k+1}^{\infty})= \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} I(X_1^k:X_{k+1}^{k+m}).
$$

Is this correct ? I am not sure where to start with to prove the above result. One can assume that it has nice properties like having density, etc if required.

Comment: I don't quite understand what it's to be proved here. The formula looks more as a definition (in general, for any vectors) than as a property to me.

Comment: @leonbloy: Think of $Y_k= (X_{k+1},X_{k+2},...)$ as a random variable taking real values in $[0,1]$ (since they all are binary. Now I want to prove that mutual information computed for two random variables $X_1^k,Y_k$ is same as the above limit.

Comment: Forget about where the vectors came from, that's irrelevant. We know the definition of  the mutual information between two (finite) vectors $I(W_1^n; U_1^m)$. What is your definition of the mutual information when a "infinite" vector is involved $I(W_1^n; U_1^\infty)$?

Comment: @leonbloy: If $X$ is a discrete random variable and $Y$ a continuous random variable, then $I(X;Y) := h(Y)-\sum_{x_i}h(Y|X=x_i)$ where $h(Y) = -\int f \log(f) $.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are taking the wrong approach to the formula. That equality is not a property to be proved from the particular properties of the vectors involved. It's rather something like a (general) definition.

The mutual information $I(X;Y)$ is well defined for any random variables $X$, $Y$. This includes multivariate random variables, which can be represented as vectors of arbitrary (finite) dimensions: $I(X_{1}^n;Y_1^m)$ Now, we might want to extend this to vectors of "infinite dimensions" (sequences). And the natural way to define the mutual information betweeen a finite vector $X_{1}^n$ and an infinite vector $Y_1^\infty$ would be:

$$I(X_1^n;Y_{1}^{\infty})= \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} I(X_1^k:Y_{1}^{m})$$

Comment: Yes, I agree. Suppose $I(X;Y)$ is defined as $h(Y)- \sum_{x_i}\mathbb{P}(X=x_i)h(Y|X=x_i)$, then will this quantity agree with the limit is my question. Please correct me if I am wrong.